# ¿Cómo eliminar un elemento de un Array en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

¿Hay alguna función sencilla para eliminar un elemento de un array en JavaScript?

Estoy insertando elementos en una Array mediante el metodo `.push()`.

Answer (score 15):

eliminar el último

```
array.pop();
```

eliminar el primero

```
array.shift();
```

eliminar uno del indice deseado

```
array.splice(x, 1);
```

donde x es el indice que deseas eliminar

Answer (score 6):

Puedes usar la siguiente solución: primero que nada buscas la posición del elemento a eliminar por ejemplo:

```
var array = [3, 5, 9];
var index = array.indexOf(5);
```

luego eliminas ese elemento usando `splice`:

```
if (index > -1) {
   array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para eliminar tiene el shift() o pop() para remover el primer o ultimo elemento

[JavaScript Array Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)

Para remover en otras posiciones usarias el [splice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) por ejemplo

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Kiwi"];
fruits.splice(2, 2);
```

el resultado seria

```
Banana,Orange,Kiwi
```

removiendo desde la segunda posicion (recuerda que el array inicia en el cero) dos elementos